# Google add GPS Markers not working : NOClassFoundError

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement the GPS Module with adding markers by touch. When it comes to the execution, is shows the following Logcat exception message.Even I go to Java Build Path -> Order and Export . From the list below uncheck the box next to "Android Dependencies". Finally clean my project and run. , it still fails to give the correct map. What else I should rectify instead ?

Logcat Message:

```
  05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074): Process: com.example.testgpsmarker, PID: 3074
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at com.example.testgpsmarker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    05-20 14:50:17.042: E/AndroidRuntime(3074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Android Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testgpsmarker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.testgpsmarker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.testgpsmarker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testgpsmarker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="3265130" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD2O3T2kWPH93YDhHMF3gDXQUSob9lAUdQ" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Source Code :

```
package com.example.testgpsmarker;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener {

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;

    Location myLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        // myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

        myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), point.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .title("You are here")           
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));  


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "New marker added@" + point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` Make sure you reference google play services properly

Comment: I have declared
  <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


What else I should refer the lib. to ?

Comment: not required. read the docs google maps api v2

Comment: I still cannot make it

Comment: Follow this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/. If you can't then atleast post the error. According to your stacktrace you haven't referenced library project google play services. google maps requires google play services. you need to setup google play services

Comment: I have also google play service lib included but it fails..

Comment: it won't you haven't followed the steps right. good luck